WinUI 3 : How to collapse navigation menu item when changing selection
Using WinUI 3
Is there any way to collapse a navigation menu item when the selection changes to another menu item?
I try to iterate through all options of the menu at the 'Selection change' event, and set the 'IsExpanded' property to 'false' if it's not the selected item. This works, but unfortunately breaks the menu selection indicator and it's animation.

Did you try NavigationView.UpdateLayout();?

The following code works but I needed to refresh IsChildSelected manually.
<NavigationView SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu A">
            <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="A-1">
                    <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                        <NavigationViewItem Content="A-1-1" />
                        <NavigationViewItem Content="A-1-2" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="A-2" />
            </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu B">
            <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="B-1" />
                <NavigationViewItem Content="B-2">
                    <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                        <NavigationViewItem Content="B-2-1" />
                        <NavigationViewItem Content="B-2-2" />
                        <NavigationViewItem Content="B-2-3" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
</NavigationView>

private void NavigationView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var item in GetAllNavigationViewItems(sender))
    {
        RefreshIsChildSelected(item);
        item.IsExpanded = item.IsChildSelected;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<NavigationViewItem> GetAllNavigationViewItems(NavigationView navigationView)
{
    foreach (var childItem in  navigationView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
    {
        yield return childItem;

        foreach (var grandChildItem in GetAllNavigationViewItems(childItem))
        {
            yield return grandChildItem;
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<NavigationViewItem> GetAllNavigationViewItems(NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem)
{
    foreach (var childItem in navigationViewItem.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
    {
        yield return childItem;

        foreach (var grandChildItem in GetAllNavigationViewItems(childItem))
        {
            yield return grandChildItem;
        }
    }
}

private void RefreshIsChildSelected(NavigationViewItem item)
{
    var childItems = item.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>().ToList();

    foreach (var childItem in childItems)
    {
        RefreshIsChildSelected(childItem);
    }

    item.IsChildSelected = childItems.Any(x => x.IsSelected is true || x.IsChildSelected is true);
}

